# Specify style for a nested tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

#### Question

How to specify the appearance of a nested `tcolorbox` which has a style defined with `\tcbset{my-box-style/.style={ ... }}`?

#### Current situation

In my document, I use `tcolorbox` package to define many environments, like theorems, lemmas, proofs and other types of boxes. All these boxes share a base style `\tcbset{my-box-style/.style={ ... }}`, but override some colors:

```
\tcbset{my-box-substyle-a/.style={ my-box-style, ... <overrides> ... }
```

I would like to control the appearance of nested boxes with a style specified in preamble. In particular, I want to change the value of the parameter `left` of a nested box.

I have tried using the key `every box on layer n` in many different ways, but I cannot get it to work.

#### Problem

The following document illustrates my problem:
[image: I want the first two inner boxes to look like the last two inner boxes, but without having to type 'left=5pt,right=5pt manually']

#### Code

Source of the picture above:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

\tcbset{my-box-style/.style={
    colback=white,
    sharp corners,
    oversize,
    left=10pt,
    right=10pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
}}

\tcbset{my-box-substyle-a/.style={
    my-box-style,
    colback=green!10,
}}
\tcbset{my-box-substyle-b/.style={
    my-box-style,
    colback=blue!10,
}}

% My failed attempt:
\tcbset{every box on layer 2/.style={
    left=5pt,
    right=5pt,
}}
% End of my attempt.

\begin{document}
I want the inner boxes from here:

\begin{tcolorbox}[my-box-substyle-a]
    Outer box.
    \begin{tcolorbox}[my-box-substyle-b]
        Inner box.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[my-box-substyle-b]
    Outer box.
    \begin{tcolorbox}[my-box-substyle-a]
        Inner box.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}

to look like the inner box here:

\begin{tcolorbox}[my-box-substyle-a]
    Outer box.
    \begin{tcolorbox}[my-box-substyle-b,left=5pt,right=5pt]
        Inner box.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[my-box-substyle-b]
    Outer box.
    \begin{tcolorbox}[my-box-substyle-a,left=5pt,right=5pt]
        Inner box.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}

without having to type \textbf{left=5pt,right=5pt} manually in each inner box in my (long) document. The order in which the styles are nested should not matter.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that styles `every box on layer n` are applied *before* the optional argument of `tcolorbox` env, hence the setting to `left` and `right` will be overwritten by the similar setting (`left=10pt, right=10pt`) in style `my-box-style`.

**Option 1:**
In the example below a `late options` style is defined by `every box on layer 2` and applied at the end of `my-box-style`.

```tex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

\tcbset{my-box-style/.style={
    colback=white,
    sharp corners,
    oversize,
    left=10pt,
    right=10pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    late options/.try,
}}

\tcbset{my-box-substyle-a/.style={
    my-box-style,
    colback=green!10,
}}
\tcbset{my-box-substyle-b/.style={
    my-box-style,
    colback=blue!10,
}}

\tcbset{every box on layer 2/.append style={
  late options/.style={
    left=5pt,
    right=5pt,
  }
}}

\begin{document}
I want the inner boxes from here:

\begin{tcolorbox}[my-box-substyle-a]
    Outer box.
    \begin{tcolorbox}[my-box-substyle-b]
        Inner box.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[my-box-substyle-b]
    Outer box.
    \begin{tcolorbox}[my-box-substyle-a]
        Inner box.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Option 2:** This time a new option `on layer={<num>}{<options>}` is provided, which I think is clearer than the `every box on layer n` way:

```tex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{
  on layer/.code 2 args={%
    \ifnum\c@tcblayer=\numexpr#1\relax
      \pgfkeysalso{#2}%
    \fi
  }
}
\makeatother

\tcbset{my-box-style/.style={
    colback=white,
    sharp corners,
    boxsep=0pt,
    on layer={1}{left=10pt, right=10pt},
    on layer={2}{left=5pt, right=5pt},
    oversize,
}}

\tcbset{my-box-substyle-a/.style={
    my-box-style,
    colback=green!10,
}}
\tcbset{my-box-substyle-b/.style={
    my-box-style,
    colback=blue!10,
}}

\begin{document}
I want the inner boxes from here:

\begin{tcolorbox}[my-box-substyle-a]
    Outer box.
    \begin{tcolorbox}[my-box-substyle-b]
        Inner box.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[my-box-substyle-b]
    Outer box.
    \begin{tcolorbox}[my-box-substyle-a]
        Inner box.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Feb 4, 2022 Update: According to `tcolorbox`'s doc for option `oversize`, I've moved `oversize` to the last. This won't change the output.

Comment: Thank you! I very much like option two; truth be told I think it should be featured in the `tcolorbox` library.